# How do I make 'foo()' and 'foo().bar()' output completely different things?

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

So I'm trying to make it so `foo()` returns anything from a string to object, then have `foo().bar()` return something completely different and even have `foo().bar().test()` return another thing completely different. For example, `databases()` would return something like a list of databases, then `databases().users()` would return an object of all the users and finally `databases().users().ids()` would return an array of IDs.

I think it's called function/method chaining but I haven't found anything related to what I need.
All I find is examples like `var number = new math(10) number.add(5).subtract(3).value` but I don't want it to chain it like that, I want it very linear (I don't know how to explain). I don't want to be able to use `number.subtract(3).add(5).value` or `databases().ids().users()` and I don't want to have to have `.value` at the end.

```js
var math = function (n) {
    this.value = n;
    this.add = function (x) {
        this.value += x;
        return this;
    };
    this.subtract = function (x) {
        this.value -= x;
        return this;
    };
};
var number = new math(10);
console.log(number.add(5).subtract(3).value);
```

The node js module, moment, works the way I'd like my project to work. `moment()` returns `Moment<...>`, `moment().hours()` returns the hour and `moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD")` returns `2020/10/22`.

Comment: The moment example is very wrong. `moment()` returns a Moment object. `moment().hours()` calls the `.hours()` method on the object. `moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD")` calls the `.format()` method on that same object. They don't return *different things* - the final value is different but only because each of the methods on the Moment wrapper returns a different thing.

Comment: @VLAZ my point still stands. `console.log(moment())` logs `Fri Oct 23 2020 00:33:37 GMT+1300`.

Comment: That's serialisation. Not the same as "a different value" - it's just automatically transformed by the console.

Comment: You're likely seeing that console output in Node.JS. This is *unique* to that environment, as Moment implements [the `nodejs.util.inspect.custom` Symbol method](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_custom) that is only respected by Node.JS. It will not be used in Firefox, or even Chrome for the console output.

Comment: @VLAZ "nodejs.util.inspect.custom" is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Playing around with it I got that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want `number` capacity and limited `string` capacity:

```
class Database extends String { 
    valueOf() { return 2 }
    users() { return { ids: () => [] } } 
}; 
const database = (val) => new Database(val || "")
```

Then you will be able to do this `database() + 2 === 4`, all string methods will be available and you will be able to do this `database().users().ids()`